# UIView in UITableViewCell Has Double Border

Tags: swift, uitableview, border

With the code below, I add a colored border and round the corners passed. However, when I resize the `UIView` programmatically, the old border remains and I get this double border:

[image: Double border on UIView within a UITableViewCell]

Anyone have an idea how to fix it? I've tried calling `cell.layoutSubviews()` and `cell.layer.layoutSublayers()`. I tried removing the border layer and setting the layers to `nil` before setting the border. Nothing seems to work.

if I don't resize the view, it's fine.

```
func roundCorners (view: UIView, corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, color: String) {
    let bounds = view.bounds

    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = bounds
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath

    view.layer.mask = maskLayer

    var borderColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    switch color {
    case "Green":
        borderColor = UIColor(red: 130/255.0, green: 208/255.0, blue: 151/255.0, alpha: 0.9)
    case "Red":
        borderColor = UIColor(red: 243/255.0, green: 44/255.0, blue: 31/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        view.alpha = 0.5
    case "Purp":
        borderColor = UIColor(red: 102/255.0, green: 135/255.0, blue: 241/255.0, alpha: 0.7)
    case "DarkBlue":
        borderColor = UIColor(red: 90/255.0, green: 125/255.0, blue: 160/255.0, alpha: 0.6)
    default:
        borderColor = UIColor(red: 150/255.0, green: 150/255.0, blue: 150/255.0, alpha: 0.7)
    }

    let frameLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    frameLayer.frame = bounds
    frameLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    frameLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
    frameLayer.lineWidth = 3
    frameLayer.fillColor = nil

    view.layer.addSublayer(frameLayer)
}
```

Called from `cellForRowAt`:

```
 roundCorners(view: cell.MoveCellTo_TodayList, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft], radius: 8, color: "Green")
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `maskLayer` and `frameLayer` out of the function's scope and call the `roundCorners` inside the cell's overridden `layoutSubviews`.

```
var maskLayer: CAShapeLayer!
var frameLayer: CAShapeLayer!

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

     roundCorners(view: MoveCellTo_TodayList, maskLayer: &maskLayer, frameLayer: &frameLayer, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft], radius: 8, color: "Green")
}

func roundCorners(view: UIView, maskLayer: inout CAShapeLayer, frameLayer: inout CAShapeLayer, corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, color: String) {
    let bounds = view.bounds

    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    if maskLayer == nil {
        maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        view.layer.mask = maskLayer

        frameLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        view.layer.addSublayer(frameLayer)
    }

    [...]
}
```